# Using regex to parse out values from dictionaries and count (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a column in a dataframe with column 'url_product' that contains a list of dictionaries as below (showing first 4 rows as an example). 
Each dictionary contains url and product associated with that url.

```
df.url_product[0] 
[{'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/product/11-abc-gift-card/',
  'product': 'giftcard, abcstore'},
 {'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/product/10-skin-lotion/',
  'product': 'lotion'},
 {'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/product/10414-moisturising-cream',
  'product': 'cream'},
 {'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/blog/best-skincare-lotions/',
  'product': 'lotion'},
 {'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/article/140-best-anti-aging-serum',
  'product': 'serum'}]

df.url_product[1] 
[{'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/product/7-night-cream',
  'product': 'nightcream'},
 {'url': 'http://www.abcstore.com/product/149-smoothing-serum/',
  'product': 'serum'},
 {'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/blog/rapid-reveal-face-peel',
  'product': 'facepeel'}]

df.url_product[2] 
[{'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/product/25-night-infusion-cream',
  'product': 'infusioncream'},
 {'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/product/144-bio-cellulose-mask',
  'product': 'cellulosemask, mask'},
 {'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/',
  'product': 'bestseller, homepage'},
 {'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/blog/essential-skincare-products/',
  'product': 'essential, blog'}]

df.url_product[3] 
[{'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/blog/top-skincare-products-2020',
  'product': 'skincare, 2020'},
 {'url': 'http://www.abcstore.com/article/smoothing-serum/',
  'product': 'serum'}]
```

For each of these rows, I am looking to do the following

1. Filter for only the dictionaries where URL contains '/product/' and parse out the number following the 'product/' (will call this **product_id** as easy reference). expected product_id of dictionary below = 11 
   `{'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/product/11-abc-gift-card/',
   'product': 'giftcard, abcstore'}`
2. For each of the dictionaries where URL contains '/product/' also count the number of 'products'. For the example below, that count would be **2** (giftcard, abcstore) 
   `{'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/product/11-abc-gift-card/',
   'product': 'giftcard, abcstore'}`
3. For each row return the **product_id** that has the highest count and create a new column('top_product_id') in the dataframe to show this. If no single product_id has the highest count, leave as blank

Expected outcome for the first 3 three rows after the steps above

df.top_product_id

```
[0] '11'
[1] (blank)
[2] '114'
[3] (blank)
```

a few points to explain the expected outcome

Row[0]- expect 11 as product_id 11 has a count of 2 (giftcard, abcstore) while product_id 10 and 10414 only has 1 each. both the blog and article urls will be skipped as they do not contain '/product/' in the url 
Row[1]- expect the outcome to be blank as the two product URLs are attached to 1 product each and since there is no single url with the highest count, row would be blank 
Row[2]- expect 114 as product_id 114 has highest count of 2 (cellulosemask, mask) 
Row[3]- expect the outcome to be blank as there are no product URLs

How would I create the new column ('top_product_id') in the dataframe with the expected outcome?

Comment: how did the data get into a dataframe? I believe it would be easier to work with the data outside a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible approach:

```
def findID(data):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df1 = df1.assign(
        count=df1['product'].str.split(', ').str.len(),
        product_id=df1['url'].str.extract(r'.*/product/(\d+)', expand=False)
    ).dropna().drop_duplicates(subset=['count'], keep=False)

    if df1.empty:
        return '(Blank)'

    return df1.loc[df1['count'].idxmax(), 'product_id']


df['top_product_id'] = df['url_product'].apply(findID)
```

---

```
# print(df)
                                         url_product top_product_id
0  [{'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/product/11-...             11
1  [{'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/product/7-n...        (Blank)
2  [{'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/product/25-...            144
3  [{'url': 'https://www.abcstore.com/blog/top-sk...        (Blank)
```